# trigger select by clicking an icon

Tags: jquery

I have a select element and want to simulate a click. The whole app is written in angularjs, but the trigger event is written in jquery. So I use the on() function like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fa', function() {
    $(this).siblings('select :selected').change();
});
```

I tried the change() function to pull down the select options. Unfortunatly it don't work. [Maybe this JSFiddle helps for better understanding.](http://jsfiddle.net/bloggerschmidt/uey4Lmtj/1/) Thanks for reply.

Comment: There must be angular way to achieve it. and your question is not clear what do you expect `.change()` will do.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried the change() function to pull down the select options.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, do you mean you want to get the value of the selected option? (when it is changed) Like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/liviugc/3fapfm8e/)

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a click on the select to open it?

Comment: Yes, I want to simulate a click on the select.

Comment: See my answer below, using an out of the box select element to perform this isn't going to be fun for you.